# React.js - react-google-maps events return

Tags: javascript, google-maps, reactjs

I'm using the react-google-maps package in React but I'm struggling to get the onDrag event from the component. My code is as follows:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import GoogleAddressAutocomplete from './googleaddressautocomplete.js';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps";
import axios from 'axios';
import NavWrapper from './navwrapper.js';

class MapPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            markers: {
                position: {
                    lat: 48.723627,
                    lng: 21.254199900000003,
                },
                key: Date.now(),
                defaultAnimation: 2,
            },
            mapCenter: { lat: 48.723627, lng: 21.254199900000003 },
            access_token: '',
            address: ''
        }
    }

    handleMapClick = this.handleMapClick.bind(this);
    handleMapDrag = this.handleMapDrag.bind(this);
    handleMapLoad = this.handleMapLoad.bind(this);

    handleMapClick(event) {
        let that = this;
        this.setState({
            markers: {
                position: event.latLng,
                defaultAnimation: 2,
                key: Date.now()
            },
            mapCenter: event.latLng
        });

    

    }

    handleAddressChange(latLngObject, address) {
        console.log('addr: => '+address);
    }

    handleMapDrag(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }

    handleMapLoad(event) {
        console.log(event);
    }

    render() {
        const GoogleMapWrapper = withGoogleMap(props => (
            <GoogleMap
                ref={props.onMapDrag}
                defaultZoom={13}
                defaultCenter={props.center}
                onClick={props.onMapClick}
                onDragEnd={props.onMapDrag}
            >
                <Marker {...props.markers} />
            </GoogleMap>
        ));

        return (
            <div className="row-100">
                <NavWrapper/>
                <GoogleAddressAutocomplete addressChange={this.handleAddressChange.bind(this)} address={this.state.address}/>
                <br />
                <GoogleMapWrapper
                    containerElement={
                        <div style={{ height: `50vh` }} />
                    }
                    mapElement={
                        <div style={{ height: `50vh` }} />
                    }
                    onMapClick={this.handleMapClick.bind(this)}
                    onMapDrag={this.handleMapDrag.bind(this)}
                    onMapLoad={this.handleMapLoad.bind(this)}
                    markers={this.state.markers}
                    center={this.state.mapCenter}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MapPage;
```

The handleMapDrag(event) function still returns 'undefined'. Could you please help? I need to get the map's center in LatLng format after the map is dragged, either on the onDragEnd event or the onDrag event itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

So the solution was to call the lat&lng functions on the actual instance, note the 'ref' property on the GoogleMaps object, it's important for proper function.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import GoogleAddressAutocomplete from './googleaddressautocomplete.js';
import { withGoogleMap, GoogleMap, Marker } from "react-google-maps";
import axios from 'axios';
import NavWrapper from './navwrapper.js';

class MapPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            markers: {
                position: {
                    lat: 48.723627,
                    lng: 21.254199900000003,
                },
                key: Date.now(),
                defaultAnimation: 2,
            },
            mapCenter: { lat: 48.723627, lng: 21.254199900000003 },
            access_token: '',
            address: '',
            mapRef: null
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        
    }

    handleMapClick = this.handleMapClick.bind(this);
    handleMapDrag = this.handleMapDrag.bind(this);
    handleMapLoad = this.handleMapLoad.bind(this);

    handleMapClick(event) {
        let that = this;
        this.setState({
            markers: {
                position: event.latLng,
                defaultAnimation: 2,
                key: Date.now()
            },
            mapCenter: event.latLng
        });

    }

    handleAddressChange(latLngObject, address) {
        console.log('addr: => '+address);
    }

    handleMapDrag() {
        let mapRef = this._mapComponent;
        console.log(mapRef.getCenter().lat()+'; '+mapRef.getCenter().lng());
    }

    handleMapLoad(map) {
        this._mapComponent = map;
    }

    render() {
        const GoogleMapWrapper = withGoogleMap(props => (
            <GoogleMap
                ref={props.onMapLoad}
                defaultZoom={13}
                defaultCenter={props.center}
                onClick={props.onMapClick}
                onDragEnd={props.onDragEnd}
            >
                <Marker {...props.markers} />
            </GoogleMap>
        ));

        return (
            <div className="row-100">
                <NavWrapper/>
                <GoogleAddressAutocomplete addressChange={this.handleAddressChange.bind(this)} address={this.state.address}/>
                <br />
                <GoogleMapWrapper
                    containerElement={
                        <div style={{ height: `50vh` }} />
                    }
                    mapElement={
                        <div style={{ height: `50vh` }} />
                    }
                    onMapClick={this.handleMapClick}
                    onDragEnd={this.handleMapDrag}
                    onMapLoad={this.handleMapLoad}
                    markers={this.state.markers}
                    center={this.state.mapCenter}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default MapPage;
```

The actual center of the map is logged to the console in the handleMapDrag() function.

Comment: If you don't mind, do you know how to change zoom control position using this package.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning that, return this:

```
return (
        <div className="row-100">
            <NavWrapper/>
            <GoogleAddressAutocomplete addressChange={this.handleAddressChange.bind(this)} address={this.state.address}/>
            <br />
            <GoogleMapWrapper
                containerElement={
                    <div style={{ height: `50vh` }} />
                }
                mapElement={
                    <div style={{ height: `50vh` }} />
                }
                onMapClick={this.handleMapClick}
                onMapDrag={this.handleMapDrag}
                onMapLoad={this.handleMapLoad}
                markers={this.state.markers}
                center={this.state.mapCenter}
            />
        </div>
    )
```

You don't need to bind "this" to the methods again in the events, you just want to call them. You just need to bind 'this' to the methods in the constructor.

Pass this:

```
handleMapClick = this.handleMapClick.bind(this);
handleMapDrag = this.handleMapDrag.bind(this);
handleMapLoad = this.handleMapLoad.bind(this);
```

to the constructor.

Not quite sure, I didn't work many times with React, but i think those may be the problems.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's basically the same binding-wise. Anyway, I found a solution to this, I'll post an answer, thanks for the involvement guys ;)

Answer (score 0):

did you try giving onDragStart to the GoogleMap Component?

Comment: the GoogleMap component does trigger the function it's event is bound to, thus dragging the map results in a console log but I'm unable to retrieve the GPS coordinates of the current map center